# Building Valama IDE on Windows using MSYS2 and MingW

Tags: windows, cmake, mingw, vala, msys2

I am using MSYS2 to build Valama [the next generation IDE for Vala].

what the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Valama/Valama) says that some dependencies are required.
and they are provided for Ubuntu using this command

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential valac-0.24 libvala-0.24-dev cmake pkg-config libgtksourceview-3.0-dev libgee-0.8-dev libxml2-dev libgdl-3-dev libgladeui-dev libclutter-gtk-1.0-dev libwebkit2gtk-3.0-dev intltool gnome-icon-theme-symbolic librsvg2-bin
```

and I started to download these dependencies using

```
pacman -S [PACKAGE NAME]
```

but these packages names are not the same in pacman for mingw as they are in apt-get for ubuntu

so I found that pacman supports searching for packages using this command

```
pacman -sS [PACKAGE NAME substring]
```

so after every successful installation I tested cmake .. command as in the GitHub repository

until I get stuck with this dependency

```
gladeui-2.0
```

and this what the log of cmake look like :

```
-- Checking for module 'gee-0.8 >= 0.10.5'
--   Found gee-0.8 , version 0.18.1
-- Update files for GtkSourceView 3.14.3
-- Use enhanced gdl-3.0 vapi to support new features with gdl-3.0 >= 3.9.91.
-- Checking for module 'gladeui-2.0'
--   No package 'gladeui-2.0' found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.6.2/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:424 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.6.2/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:597 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:201 (pkg_check_modules)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/e/valama/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/e/valama/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

as you can see from the log that [gladeui-2.0] is not found on the MSYS-mingw subsystem, and I failed to find the supported library for it.

what I am asking is what is the command to install the remaining dependencies of valama, or how to build them and install them, including gladeui-2.0.

Answer (score 0):

On the [MSYS2 home page](http://www.msys2.org/) there are two GitHub repositories listed for issues with packages. The first is [issues for msys2 packages on GitHub](https://github.com/alexpux/msys2-packages/issues) and the second is [issues for mingw-w64 packages on GitHub](https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages). Both of these repositories list packages as sub-directories.

The most interesting are the mingw-w64 packages, which includes `mingw-w64-glade` and `mingw-w64-glade3`. So you could try installing either of those. Glade3 is the newer version, but Valarama may be dependent on the older Glade 2.

Comment: thanks alot , but I already searched for that and find this repo , and installed all [glade related] packages; but it did not solve the issue